# Достать элемент из массива ( после json_decode())

Tags: php

Не выходит достать значение ID из массива,

```
    Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 210
                    [TITLE] => Форма с локалки
                    [HONORIFIC] =>
                    [NAME] => ALEX33
                )
          )

    [total] => 1
)
```

пробую так:

```
foreach ($result as $key){
    //echo "arr =". $key;  // получаем два массива result и total

    foreach ($key[0] as $v){  // пытаюсь достучатся до первого массива result

        echo $v;

     }
}
```

Comment: `$arr = array(
    'result' => array(
        array(
            'ID' => 210,
            'TITLE' => 'Форма с локалки',
            'HONORIFIC' => '',
            'NAME' => 'ALEX33'
        )
    ),

    'total' => 1
);

foreach ($arr as $arr_2) { 
    echo $arr_2[0]['ID']; // 210
}`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!